# What is the big O notation here and how do I figure it out?

Tags: ruby, big-o

There are 1805 elements in this array.  I am looping through each one of them and outputting the ID and destroying the follower.
How do I find the big O notation here?

Would the better and quicker option be to use followers.destroy_all?

```
followers.each { |f| puts f.id; f.destroy! };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the source code of [`destroy_all`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L579) then you will notice that it basically does the same as your example. It iterates over all records in the relation and calls `destroy` on each of them. I expect it still to be a bit faster than your version because calling `puts` doesn't come for free. But both versions are `O(n)`

If possible you might want to use [`delete_all`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation#delete_all-instance_method) instead which doesn't load all records into memory and doesn't call `destroy` on every single element. Instead, it deletes all records in the relation with one single SQL query which makes this method way faster than `destroy_all`. But of course `delete_all` doesn't trigger callbacks and therefore might not work for you.